# Software, extension, or similar to remove select results from Internet search

Tags: security, firefox, search-engine

I do searches on the net and frequently see obviously bad results float to the top.  I primarily search in Firefox, or a Firefox clone or derivative, using DuckDuckGo.  These types of sites come up looking for reviews, software, alternatives, etc.  To the trained(?) human eye, they are immediately obviously not something I want to click on, but I wonder if they have already been blacklisted somewhere.  After all, the people behind these sites are getting more clever and more nefarious and I find myself falling for them more often, and some of them sound legit and use English instead of auto-generated text or Engrish.

Here's a concrete example.  I came across some videos lamenting YouTube's clash with "the studios" and "Hollywood" recently, using the hashtag #WTFU (stands for Where's The Fair Use?).  I was wondering if there are viable alternatives to YouTube, so I searched for "alternatives to youtube".  Here are the top few results:

> Top 10 Best Alternatives To YouTube - TheTopTens.com
> thetoptens.com/best-alternatives-youtube/
>
> 5 Video Sites That Are Alternatives to YouTube - MakeUseOf
> makeuseof.com/tag/5-video-sites-alternatives-to-youtube/
>
> YouTube Alternatives: 7 Best Video Sharing Sites For 2015
> beebom.com/2014/02/youtube-alternatives
>
> YouTube Alternatives and Similar Software - AlternativeTo.net
> alternativeto.net/software/youtube/
>
> 10 YouTube Alternatives for Small Businesses
> [Search domain smallbiztrends.com] smallbiztrends.com/2014/01/youtube-alternatives-small-busine...
>
> 5 Alternatives to YouTube - ZeroPaid.com
> zeropaid.com/news/101707/5-alternatives-youtube/

If you didn't know that MakeUseOf, TopTens, and AlternativeTo.net were clickbat/scams/garbage already, you might be impressed by their domain names.  However, it's 2016 and the more relevent a domain name is, the more I suspect it of being over-commercialized to the point of being a scam, if not fraud.

Is there some kind of extension, plugin, or other tool I could make use of to warn me of these?

I guess [Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/) purports to do what I want, but I'm still not sold on it (I don't know why).  Maybe I'm worried about it leaking details and false positives for opinions like political sites.  I am primarily interested in sites that will harm my computer.  I'm a grown up and can handle things that may or may not harm my eyes.

Comment: do **NOT install** the so called "Web of Trust" (**WOT**), it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html